# Weird C2143 error with two consecutive if constexpr in the same function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-c++-2019

I am compiling the following code with c++17:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void barA() const {std::cout << "barA\n";}
};

struct B {
    void barB() const {std::cout << "barB\n";}
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool isBaseA() {
    return std::is_base_of<A, T>::value;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool isBaseB() {
    return std::is_base_of<B, T>::value;
}

template<typename... Args>
class K : public Args... {
public:
void foo() {
    using MyK = K<Args...>;
    
    if constexpr(isBaseA<MyK>()) {
        using X = typename MyK::A;
        X::barA();
    }
    if constexpr(isBaseB<MyK>()) {
        using X = typename MyK::B;
        X::barB();
    }
}
};

int main()
{
    K<A, B> k;
    k.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ga68hf8bz)

When building with MSVC 2019 (version 16.8.30804.86, it should be the last available one), I am getting a weird C2143 error at the line

```
void foo() {
```

The complete C2143 error is :

```
<source>(24): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
<source>(24): note: while compiling class template member function 'void K<A,B>::foo(void)'
<source>(41): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void K<A,B>::foo(void)' being compiled
<source>(40): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'K<A,B>' being compiled
<source>(24): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ')'
<source>(24): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

I noticed that:

- if I comment the second `if constexpr` block of the function `foo`, the error goes away;
- if I don't define the alias `using MyK = K<Args...>;`, the error goes away.

The code works fine both on gcc and clang.
Is this just a MSVC bug, or am I breaking the c++17 standard somewhere in the code?

Comment: please post the complete error message. Error codes are compiler specific, but the error itself (compiler bugs aside) is universal

Comment: Despite what you might think, most people don't memorize Microsoft's error codes, and making people google for "C2143" isn't very nice. In particular since you have the actual complete message right in front of you, ready to be copied and pasted.

Comment: @molbdnilo, sorry, I did not paste the message because I have the italian language in the PC and msvc translates everything. I thought that the code was enough, but I was wrong! Sorry again, I edited the question

Comment: `if constexpr` only "works" in a function templates.  `foo` is not a function template.

Comment: Also looks like a compiler bug to me. Reduced test case: https://godbolt.org/z/ao39f1x1b

Comment: The comment from @NathanOliver seems to suggest that it is the other compilers that are wrong. However, the error messages from MSVC are not helpful: *error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'* and *error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ')'*

Comment: ... also, making `foo` a function template doesn't fix the errors.

Comment: ... However, removing *either* of the `if constexpr...` blocks removes the error. ?!?

Comment: @user17732522 twisted. compiles with v19.15, fails with v19.16 and beyond.

Comment: @NathanOliver It is part of a class template though, so it still "works".

Comment: Moving the tests out of the _constexpr-if_ [workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/KdnaWKE16) - or even [`bool(isBaseA<MyK>())`](https://godbolt.org/z/94MExcaWq)

Comment: @user17732522 That doesn't matter for `if constexpr`.  Since it is a non-template member, then when the function is stamped out with the class, `MyK` is no longer non-deduced, it has a concrete type, and `if constexpr` only does its magic in a non-deduced context.

Comment: @NathanOliver however, I had this error the first time in a templated member function. I then simplified the code as much as I could to ask the question on stackoverflow. I mean... your point seems to be unrelated with the error that msvc prompts

Comment: @NathanOliver: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if), *"If a constexpr if statement appears inside a templated entity, and if condition is not value-dependent after instantiation, the discarded statement is not instantiated when the enclosing template is instantiated ."* it seems it only need templated entity, and `K<Args...>::foo` is.

Comment: @AdrianMole afaik `if constexpr` may be used outside of templates, but then nothing will be discarded. Its not an error, just not that useful

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see why that is. If you remove the part msvc has a problem with, all compilers agree that the discarded `if constexpr` statements are not instantiated: https://godbolt.org/z/TE3a39Tez The standard requires only that it appears in a templated entity (and the condition not being value-dependent after instantiation e.g. in nested templates): https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.if-2

Comment: @user17732522 But, in OP's code, there *may* be an issue with conflicting definitions of `using X...`. I tried making the second one `using Y...`  but that made no difference.

Comment: @AdrianMole These are in different scopes. One is not reachable from the other.

Comment: Just guessing, really ... definitely *smells* like a bug in MSVC. As I mentioned earlier, removing one of the `if constexpr...` blocks resolves the error, but I can't understand why.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I'll try to report the error to the microsoft folks and see what they say :)

Comment: Work-around: create a new  `constexpr bool isBaseAValue = isBaseA<MyK>();` and use it in`if constexpr(isBaseAValue)`, instead of having the original expression in the `if`. See https://godbolt.org/z/3EMGjKW88

Comment: Another thing that works, is to add extra parens:
`    if constexpr((isBaseA<MyK>())) {`
This seems like a parser bug to me

Comment: Here is the link of the ticket opened in the microsoft developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Weird-msvc-C2143-error-with-two-consecut/1646563?entry=myfeedback

Comment: Update: it was a msvc bug and it has been solved. The fix is available in the last release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a parser bug, as adding parentheses avoids the error. Adding parentheses should have no effect at all in this context:

```
template<typename... Args>
class K : public Args... {
public:
void foo() {
    using MyK = K<Args...>;
    
    // extra parentheses to overcome MSVC error
    if constexpr((isBaseA<MyK>())) {
        using X = typename MyK::A;
        X::barA();
    }
    if constexpr(isBaseB<MyK>()) {
        using X = typename MyK::B;
        X::barB();
    }
}
};
```

[compiler explorer working example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:34,endLineNumber:27,positionColumn:34,positionLineNumber:27,selectionStartColumn:34,selectionStartLineNumber:27,startColumn:34,startLineNumber:27),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%0A++++void+barA()+const+%7Bstd::cout+%3C%3C+%22barA%5Cn%22%3B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+B+%7B%0A++++void+barB()+const+%7Bstd::cout+%3C%3C+%22barB%5Cn%22%3B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconstexpr+bool+isBaseA()+%7B%0A++++return+std::is_base_of%3CA,+T%3E::value%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconstexpr+bool+isBaseB()+%7B%0A++++return+std::is_base_of%3CB,+T%3E::value%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Aclass+K+:+public+Args...+%7B%0Apublic:%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++using+MyK+%3D+K%3CArgs...%3E%3B%0A++++%0A++++if+constexpr((isBaseA%3CMyK%3E()))+%7B%0A++++++++using+X+%3D+typename+MyK::A%3B%0A++++++++X::barA()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++if+constexpr(isBaseB%3CMyK%3E())+%7B%0A++++++++using+X+%3D+typename+MyK::B%3B%0A++++++++X::barB()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++K%3CA,+B%3E+k%3B%0A++++k.foo()%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.7446363160649,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:g112,options:%27-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic+-Werror+-O2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-m32%27),(compilerId:clang1300,options:%27-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic+-Werror+-O2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest+/Wall+/permissive-%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/10%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:42.255363683935116,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Thanks!! I suspected it was a bug.. I reported it to the microsoft community!

Comment: @AlessandroMuntoni Please share the link to the report to make it easier to everyone getting stuck with the same problem to vote on the report.

Comment: It is available now! Here it is the link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Weird-msvc-C2143-error-with-two-consecut/1646563?entry=myfeedback

Comment: It was indeed a msvc bug and it has been solved! The fix is available in the last release